# ASP.net 4.0 Framework application embedded with in WSS 3.0

Tags: authentication, asp.net-4.0, wss-3.0

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 application running under WSS 3.0, and getting an error
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.get_UseMembershipUserKey()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPHttpHandler.OverrideExecuteUrlPath()
at System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Any suggestions or work around for this issue?
I am using forms based authentication for the ASP.net 4.0 application.

Thanks